# iterating a list with ForEach

Tags: vb.net, list, foreach

I have a list like this

```
Dim emailList as new List(Of String)
emailList.Add("one@domain.com")
emailList.Add("two@domain.com")
emaillist.Add("three@domain.com")
```

How can I iterate the list with ForEach to get one string with the emails like this

```
one@domain.com;two@domain.com;three@domain.com
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure why you would want to use a foreach instead of a String.Join statement. You could simply String.Join() the list using a semi-colon as your joining character.

```
String.Join(";", emailList.ToArray())
```

Comment: @NebuSoft - I completely forgot about this ... I must be getting old ... +1 for you ... I withdraw my answer.

Comment: that wouldn't work.  The second parameter is a string array, not a generic list.

Comment: I apologize, I haven't used VB since VB6. In C# you can take the generic list to an array (emailList.ToArray())...I'm sure there is an equivalent via VB.NET

Comment: is there a way to use this mechanism if the list of of integers?

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
Dim stringValue As String = String.Join(";", emailList.ToArray)
```

Have a look at [String.Join Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't actually use a ForEach loop for this.  Here is what I would do:

```
String.Join(";", emailList.ToArray());
```

Answer (score 2):

```
       Dim emailList As New List(Of String)
    emailList.Add("one@domain.com")
    emailList.Add("two@domain.com")
    emailList.Add("three@domain.com")

    Dim output As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder
    For Each Email As String In emailList
        output.Append(IIf(String.IsNullOrEmpty(output.ToString), "", ";") & Email)
    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim emailList As New StringBuilder()

For Each (email As String In emails)
     emailList.Append(String.Format("{0};", email))
Next

Return emailList.ToString()
```

Forgive me if there are any syntax errors ... my VB.NET is a little rusty and I don't have a complier handy.